# replace first digit by a letter when first digit is also in the rest of the cell in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I wish to replace the first digit (9109) by the letter "i" in my excel worksheet column `A1`.
Every cell has a different project number but every project starts with "9", so I wish to replace the "9" with the letter "i".

Very important: Bear in mind that some of my project numbers look like 9109, 9269. So I need to replace only the first "9". Can anyone help me?

Comment: like `=replace(A1,1,1,"i")` ?

Answer (score 0):

VBA:

```
Sub test()
Dim original As String
Dim replacement As String

    For Each c In Range("A:A")

        If Left(c, 1) = 9 Then

        original = c.Value
        replacement = replace(original, "9", "i", 1, 1)
        c.Value = replacement

        End If

    Next

End Sub
```